Why Do I get a 500 Internal Server Error When Deploying A Laravel App to the Project Root Directory In Virtual Hosts Configuration?
My app will open to the laravel root if my vritual host config is like so:
DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/rtracker/public/
<Directory  /var/www/apps/rtracker/public/>

But if I change to the project root like so:
DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/rtracker/public/receipts/
<Directory  /var/www/apps/rtracker/public/receipts/>

I get a 500 Internal Serer Error and apache error says this:
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Any idea why? I have tried the suggestions I found on stackoverflow, related to .htaccess, without success.
